# Do channels overlap in multiple remote controls for outlets?

Tags: receptacle

My dad just bought remote controlled outlets, which operate at 433.92mhz. The remote has four channels that can be used to control different outlets. Now what happens if I myself, buy a second set? Will the second remote have the same channels and thus interfere with the other remote?

This seems like a pretty basic question, but I must not be very good at googling, because I couldn't seem to find an answer. So does anybody out here now more about this and how to deal with several remotes in such an environment. My dad would be playing around with them closer than 30 meters, so would they interfere and if so, how could we deal with the situation?

The product is the HE808SF switch set from Home Easy. [Here](https://www.reichelt.de/HOME-easy/ELRO-HE808S/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=4555&ARTICLE=135910&OFFSET=16&SID=10VWUfE6wQATIAAFgVxww93497ba4e24ccf3bf2e40aab5f328956&LANGUAGE=EN) you can find some of its specs. [HE844 from elro](http://www.elro.eu/uploads/products/manual/HE844A_Manual.pdf)(pdf) is the remote control.

Comment: Please post the product and any details.

Comment: @Kris Added some product details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manufacturers manual that you provided, individual receivers can be "*linked*" to 1 of the 4 buttons on the transmitter.  This gives you the option to assign multiple receivers to a single button.  The Master button turns on/off all *linked* devices.

Linking is how the transmitter stores unique IDs in the EEPROM which maps the transmitters buttons to the corresponding receiver(s).

You should not have any problems with cross-communication with your dad's remote or receivers.

You may have a rare problem with signal collision if both transmitters are being used at the same time and are within close proximity.  This *might* result in neither working at all until one or the other has stop transmitting.

Comment: All right, that sounds like good news. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered with the information given. Remote controls of this type may be controlled by a small custom microprocessor that uses a protocol on the 433MHz modulation that is completely proprietary and unknown.

On the other hand there are a couple of mass manufactured IC chips designed to act as the transmitter modulator and a receiver decoder on a companion set of devices. These devices typically are setup to work with a modulation coding that supports 10 to 16 bits of variable information to be included in the transmission. Low cost remote control devices that support multiple channels will use several of these bits to encode the channel code and maybe one for on/off. So a 4 channel device could feasibly be using 3 out of the total bits. It is completely up to device manufacturer to determine how to connect the other bits as long as the transmitter and receiver use the same code. The manufacturer may hard wire the code in the PCB layout. Or they may provide a small switch to set the code. With 7 bits it would be feasible that (2^7) 128 different sets of 4 channel controllers could be used in the same location.

I have previously purchased and used low cost remote controls consisting of a two channel fob and a small 12V powered relay module receiver. These use one type of the mass produced IC chip sets. The manufacturer chose to allow the extra bits to be setup using solder pad jumpers as shown in the picture below. (Picture shows receiver. The fobs are similarly equipped).

[image]